# java help turning string array into double array

Tags: java

I have a full 1d array of data in String. I need this 1d array turned into a double array for calculations purposes. but I can't figure it out. If I can figure it out that would be great. I'm not sure but if I can read in data file AS a double and parse the white space inbetween the data that would be awesome too.  p.s. the data is arranged as coordinates not bunched up as shown below but the way I'm doing this they wont be read as an x and y but only a 1d array line.

code:

```
file = new File("subtractedvectors.txt");
    scan = new Scanner(file);

    String [] subarray = new String[40];


    for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
    {
        subarray[row] = scan.nextLine();
    }


    for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
    {
        System.out.println(subarray[row] + " ");
    }
```

data:

```
-0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 
-0.3356446340499999 -0.422276631525 
-1.0879343110499997 -0.311055704525 
-1.8794583530499998 1.268985311475 
-2.0487925240499996 -3.404131234525 
-0.7463400580499997 -0.05142237152500001 
1.2400316559500002 2.965222622475 
1.1715767139500004 -1.1113755165249999 
-0.4877369190499996 0.020307310475000007 
-0.8296528740499998 -0.611436447525 
0.43321626695000015 1.483144874475 
-0.4486841620499997 -4.199991639525 
-0.5980551060499999 -0.180287944525 
-0.9379483020499997 -1.605169775525 
0.15643726595000018 -2.591523262525 
2.19071678095 -1.041180241525 
-0.035047204049999614 0.107759270475 
-0.2796619480499998 1.174812069475 
-0.36357588404999985 -1.952647147525 
-0.1541381710499996 4.825189096475 
-0.5386256110499996 -0.129932855525 
-0.45958803605 1.054999589475 
0.5778822969500004 -1.580357584525 
2.1483562569500005 2.572258306475 
1.27904823795 1.228401456475 
0.9637480429500003 -1.766055860525 
0.33140834695 -0.18790365852500002 
-0.047555686049999935 2.585936438475 
1.2005633959500002 0.22278022747500004 
-1.4305940340499999 -1.694298031525 
-0.41707550904999957 -1.004148960525 
0.3517812019500002 0.599364130475 
-0.4172730140499996 3.248876134475 
-1.0244646370499997 2.770375020475 
-0.9653208200499999 -3.841495616525 
-0.7291669410499997 1.323124606475 
2.3113769619500006 -2.065505287525 
2.0595313709500003 1.454475365475 
-1.0216935320499998 1.511419720475 
1.15528856295 -0.683638613525
```

Comment: Just use [`Double.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)). What's stopping you?

Comment: Also, the string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Comment: @JBNizet and rohit, i think what Jack meant was to convert a string into double using `Double.parseDouble(str);`, ofcourse casting is not appropriate in this case.. :)

Comment: @PremGenError - Correct.

Comment: yeah see im not sure how to do this either. can i read it in using nextDouble() but parsing out white space so it will read the whole line not just the first set?

Comment: @Gray - Loop through the lines, grab the strings (representing doubles) that you want, and convert them to doubles via `Double.valueOf()`. This is not difficult.

Comment: i previously tried creating a new array and i used both double.parseDouble as well as Double.valueOf(), and i keep getting numberformatexceptions due to the white space thats inbetween the data points.

Comment: @Gray.. You need to first split the input line on `whitespace` to get two values as separate array elements.

Comment: @JackManey- could you show me how to do this using my code i have?

Comment: @Gray - `split` each line on whitespace. Look at the documentation. I already *am* telling you how to do this.

Comment: @RohitJain- well the problem is after i can get these values to doubles ive got to get the transpose of each vector and then do some calculation for a class project, and if i split them into to seperate data then  it will just cause me more problems

Comment: @Gray.. What's the problem. By splitting your input line, you get a 2-element string array. You can convert it to a `1 * 2` double array. Move `str[0][0]` to `num[0][0]`, and `str[0][1]` to `num[1][0]`, and you get the transpose. Where `str` is string array, and num is double array.

Comment: im in an algorithm class and our professor is not allowed to help us, and most of this stuff i havnt done before. i understand it can be really simple, but its different being told what to do vs being shown what to do ya know.

Comment: @Doug - Yes, it most certainly does matter, since it is extremely unlikely at best that OP's professor is not allowed to help OP.

Comment: Orthogonal to the discussion at hand.

Comment: @Doug - Not if it's the reason why OP asked the question in the first place.

Comment: That has no bearing on whether the question has value on Stack Overflow. It's either useful to a general audience or not - you can vote to close. Attempting to steer the discussion away from clarifying what the OP is asking (i.e. why they are asking it) is of no benefit.

Comment: @Doug - Who said it did? OP said that OP's professor wasn't allowed to help OP. I asked for clarification. That's what comments are for: asking for (and giving) clarification.

Comment: @Gray - can you please try to elaborate what you need? You currently have a `String[]` array. You seem to want a `Double[]` array, but this confuses us because your data appears to be laid out in meaningful pairs (to quote you, coordinates) and 1D array is flat. I would personally consider a `Coordinate` class, that has two fields: *x* and *y*, both of which are a `Double`. You could then have a `List<Coordinate>` that you create as you read either lines (which you parse using `split`), or by reading two consecutive `Double` values (using my nextDouble example)

Comment: @Doug well your right and that may be easier. what im needing is after i get an array of doubles i need to refer to each line as maybe a 2d array if that work because i got to get the transpose. so lets take this a different way. for example subarray[0][0] needs to reference -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 and subarray[1][0] needs to reference the next set of points going all the way down. so you can think of this array as a [40][1]. sorry for the confusion. this is a very difficult assignment

Comment: @Gray - " for example subarray[0][0] needs to reference -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 " Then `subarray` does not include doubles. It's that simple.

Comment: lets change this up a little bit:

Comment: code: double [][] subarray = new double[40][1];
  for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
  {
   for(int col = 0; col < subarray[row].length; col++)
   {
    subarray[row][col] = scan.nextDouble();
    
   }
  }
  
  
  for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
  {
   for(int col = 0; col < subarray[row].length; col++)
   {
    System.out.println(subarray[row][col] + " ");
   }
  }                                                          this print out the data as -0.2869350880499999 
0.01840283447500002 
-0.3356446340499999

Comment: @JackManey just stop man if your not going to help, as i said this is a difficult assignment, im trying my best to logically think about what i need and what you guys are helping with. subarray[0][0] needs to reference the points  -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 laid out beside each other not on top of each other

Comment: @Gray - I **am** trying to help. Do you make a habit of heaping such abuse upon those who are trying to help you? Do you actually want help?

Comment: @Gray - "subarray[0][0] needs to reference the points -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002" Again: what you want `subarray[0][0]` to equal is **not** a double. It sounds as though you want to turn `subarray[0][0]` into a `Double[2]` (or to an `ArrayList` containing two doubles, or to a custom object that acts as a pair of coordinates, etc), but your explanations are so poor that I don't know for certain what you actually want.

Comment: @JackManey yes but your criticizing more than helping. once again i havnt done this before. trying my best to logically attempt to lay out my question

Comment: @Gray - Then can you please at least attempt to answer the questions asked of you in these comments?

Comment: @JackManey maybe your right and i cant do this the way i want. the white space inbetween the points should be ignored IF i can do this. but basically going down the list subarray[0][0] should reference -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 and subarray[1][0] should reference the next set and so forth so that when i print out lets say subarray[0][0] if will print just like  -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002. BUT im not sure if i was able to do this in the first place i was just assuming that i could. i appologize for the inconvience if i have been hard to help.

Comment: @Gray - Again: I have **no idea** what you want. When you say things like "subarray[0][0] should reference -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002", then what you want is clearly **not** an array of array of doubles. That's the only thing that I know about what you want.

Comment: @Gray, question is closed but you should start looking beyond using just an array of primitive types. That's the best advice I can give you. If you had a `Coordinate` you could think of it as representing "x, y" but with x and y as distinct, typed fields. It's essentially a tuple, but Java does not have an inherent notion of such a thing. Look at [a tutorial](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html) on 2-D arrays if you want to understand better how they would be used, but again, you really only need a 1-D array (or a List or a Set) of coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.
 What this code does is it reads the string array.
Splits it into two parts based on a single space between two numbers
And then parses it to double

```
String [] subarray = new String[40];
for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
{
  subarray[row] = scan.nextLine();
}
double [][] myDoubleArray = new double[40][2];
for(int row = 0; row < subarray.length; row++)
{
  String s = subarray[row].split();//assuming that two doubles are seperated by a space  
  myDoubleArray[row][0] = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
  myDoubleArray[row][1] = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
}
```

Comment: see the problem with this is that it will give me a 2d array, its got to stay a 1d array for instance subarray[0] needs to be -0.2869350880499999 0.01840283447500002 and so forth.

Comment: @Gray - Then what you want is an array of strings, **not** an array of doubles. So, in that case, why did you ask this question in the first place?

Comment: @JackManey- so there isnt a way of doing this the way im thinking i need it done? can i read it in ignoring the white space starting as a double and ^ didnt compile either

Comment: @Gray - Doubles (when converted to strings) don't include white space. At this point, I have no idea what you think you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` you are using with supports looking for a `Double` with a particular delimiter.

```
String input = "-1.25 1.65\n 1.47 5.72";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
scanner.useDelimiter("[\\r\\n\\s]+");

while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
   System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

Output:

```
-1.25
1.65
1.47
5.72
```

The delimiter in my example should work for you based on the sample data in your question. Rather than use an array, might I suggest a `List`?